# KubernetesでLiveness Probe、Readiness Probeに指定したURL内がエンコード化される

Tags: kubernetes

KubernetesにおいてHTTP GET方式でヘルスチェック（Liveness Probe、Readiness Probe）を
実施しようとしています。
ymlファイル内でLiveness Probe、Readiness ProbeのURLに疑問符「?」が含まれているせいで
Pod起動後にdescribeで詳細を見るとURL内の疑問符「?」の部分が「%3F」に変換（エンコード化）され
Liveness Probe、Readiness Probeに失敗してしまいます。
このような場合、どのように対処すればよいか何か知恵をいただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。